# Swift 4 reverse change height of a UIView

Tags: uiview, progress-bar, height, swift4

I would like to build a progressbar. I took a rectangular view (progressBarBckgr) and put another one in front of it (progressBar).

The one in the front should increase its height by tabbing on the correct answer within a quiz app.

```
 func updateUI () {
        let numberOfAllQuestions = allQuestion.questionList.count
        print(numberOfAllQuestions) //prints 3


        let progressBarBckgrHeight = progressBarBckgr.frame.size.height
        let progressBarBckgrHeightInt = Int(progressBarBckgrHeight)
        let progressBarBckgrHeightPiece = progressBarBckgrHeightInt / numberOfAllQuestions

        progressBarOutlet.frame.size.height = (progressBarBckgr.frame.height) +  CGFloat (progressBarBckgrHeightPiece)      
    }
```

So with every correct clicked answer the progressbar  should increase just so far, that in the end of quiz the whole backgroundprogressbar is covered.

Example:
10 Questions
-> clicked answer fills increases the progressbar's height for 1/10

In addition to that i would like to increase the bar from the bottom to the top. As i enter the property height to increase it, it only gets bigger in direction bottom. Is there a nice turnaround trick?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also need to move the view up by the amount of height you have increased (`progressBarBckgrHeightPiece`)

Also, you should set the `frame` directly.

```
progressBarOutlet.frame = CGRect(x: progressBarOutlet.frame.origin.x,
                                 y: progressBarOutlet.frame.origin.y - progressBarBckgrHeightPiece, // Notice here
                                 width: progressBarOutlet.frame.width,
                                 height: progressBarOutlet.frame.height + CGFloat(progressBarBckgrHeightPiece))
```